# DBT Power user - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'webview')

Tags: visual-studio-code, dbt

I installed the Dbt power user extension on VS Code, and initially, it worked flawlessly. However, after restarting my computer, it stopped functioning. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but the problem persisted. After numerous attempts, I managed to resolve a significant portion of the issue, and now it is working again. However, I still encounter the problem "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'webview')." Has anyone else experienced this issue before, and if so, how did they manage to solve it?

[image]

here is my settings.json

```
{
"dbt.queryLimit": 100,
"dbt.powerUser": {
    "dbtPath": "/home/me/my_folder/my_sub_folder/.venv/bin/dbt",
    "targetName": "dev",
    "profilesDir": "/home/me/my_folder_/my_sub_folder_/my_cloud/dbt/profiles"
},
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "DBT_PROFILES_DIR": "./dbt/profile/"
},
"[jinja-sql]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"files.associations": {
    "*.sql": "jinja-sql"
},
"terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in version 0.17.4. Please update to the latest version of the extension.